# Placing the data in respective field names in a CSV file Using Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, split

Im writing a script that extracts the data in a txt file and write in CSV file....I can able to Split the data but could not able to place it in the correct field name......

The file will be like this:

```
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  5466 78455" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  8795 32133" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  5995 21384" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  6546 12346" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq  7895 13246" yyyy = "wwww" zzzz = "hhhh" mmmm = "aaaa"
xxxx = "qqqqqqq 64654 94343" yyyy = "wwww" mmmm = "aaaa
```

And the code I'm using is:

```
import csv
import re


fileread = str(input("enter the name of the file :"))
fread = open(fileread, "r")

resultFile = open("out3.csv",'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)


try:

    for lines in fread:
        if "attack" in lines:
            regexs = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',lines)
            wr.writerow(regexs)

finally:
    fread.close()
    resultFile.close()
```

The result is coming as:

```
      xxxx             yyyy   zzzz   mmmm

qqqqqqq  5466 78455    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  8795 32133    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  5995 21384    hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  6546 12346    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  7895 13246    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  4654 94343    wwww   aaaa
```

But I needed the output as:

```
      xxxx             yyyy   zzzz   mmmm

qqqqqqq  5466 78455    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  8795 32133    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  5995 21384           hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  6546 12346    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  7895 13246    wwww   hhhh   aaaa
qqqqqqq  4654 94343    wwww          aaaa
```

I Don't know how to place it.....
Kindly Pls!!! help me in this....

Thanks In Advance.......

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your regular expression doesn't even attempt to match the field names, it just matches everything in quotes.

If you write a regular expression that does match the field names, then you'll get the field names. For example:

```
re.findall(r'(\S+?)\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\"',line)
```

This matches a group of non-whitespace characters followed by any whitespace, an `=`, any whitespace, and a group of anything in quotes. Since there are two capturing groups, each output element will be a 2-tuple, like:

```
('xxxx', 'qqqqqqq  5466 78455')
```

So you can just convert the list of 2-tuples into a `dict`, and use `csv.DictWriter` to match the field names with the CSV volume names.