# Place the data with respect to its variable (column)

Tags: python

```
CustomerID  cs_cookie   cs_referer      cs_host sc_status   sc_substatus    sc_win32_status sc_bytes    cs_bytes    
  1     Kommarajula http    rewardcenter    200  0             0               3189           2767          62      
  2     Kommarajula http    rewardcenter    200  0             0              61828           2767         156      
  2     Kommarajula http    rewardcenter    200  0             0               3445           2750          62      
  3     Kommarajula http    rewardcenter    200  0             0              19738           2782          78      
  4     Kommarajula http    rewardcenter    200  0             0              19738           2781          78      
  5     Kommarajula v1:1    rewardcenter    200  0             0              51396           2253         374      
  6     Kommarajula v1:1    rewardcenter    200  0             0               2357           2201         124      
  7     Kommarajula v1:1    rewardcenter    200  0             0              19594           2243         140      
  8     Kommarajula Ram v1:1    rewardcenter    200            0                 0            22778       2425          109 
  9     Kommarajula Ram v1:1    rewardcenter    200            0                 0            28186       2460          296 
 10     Kommarajula Ram Kumar   v1:1    rewardcenter          200                0              0         28186         2460    296
 11     Kommarajula Ram Kumar   v1:1    rewardcenter          200                0              0         28186         2460    296
```

I have the IIS log data in csv format, but the "cs_cookie" variable has spilled in to many columns, i want place the data in to its corresponding variable after deleting the "cs_cookie" variable. please help me.

Comment: I want the following output format.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717969/placing-the-data-in-respective-field-names-in-a-csv-file-using-python?rq=1

Comment: Kasramvd@Can you help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_columns = IIS.columns.values[0:24].tolist()
count=[]
for i in range(len(IIS['CustomerID'])):
iis_list = []
iis_list = IIS.loc[i].tolist()
iis_list = [x for x in iis_list if str(x) != 'nan']
count.append(len(iis_list))

IIS['count']=count
out_list = []

for i in IIS.values.tolist():
if i[len(IIS.columns)-1] > 24:
    out_list.append(i[0:16]+i[28:36])
else:
    out_list.append(i[0:24])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(out_list)
new_df.columns = new_columns
```

Comment: Check the code with above data, you can understand, what i wanted to get.